# SecurityContext is null even if it was instantiated in SecurityContextHolder

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have a problem with Spring Security. When I'm trying to authenticate an user on my application, I'm redirected back to signin.html. After debugging, I saw that even if I'm instantiating SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(); , SecurityContext is null.

This is my authentication code:

```
public boolean dbAuthentication(String username, String password) {
            Boolean response = false;
            try {
                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                response = passwordEncoder.matches(password, userDetails.getPassword());
                if(response) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                response = false;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

This is my WebSecurityConfig class:

```
   public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfig appConfig;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() throws Exception{
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers( "/build/**","/ext/**","/resources/**","../../../resources/**","/../../resources/**","../resources/**");
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.
                    csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).
                    headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::sameOrigin))
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(a -> a
                            .requestMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/signin.html").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/forgot.html").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/getCustomCss/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/oauth2sso/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/isLdapEnabled/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/isSamlEnabled/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/prefetchFiles*").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/languages/getLanguages*").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/getSessionTimeout").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/wakeUpElastic/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/forgotPassword*").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/recoverPassword*").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/authenticate*").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/build/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/ext/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/logout*").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    ).formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.loginPage("/signin.html").
                            usernameParameter("username")
                            .passwordParameter("password")
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html", true)
                            .failureUrl("/signin.html?error=true"))
                    .logout(l -> l
                            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                            .deleteCookies("SESSIONID")
                            .logoutUrl("/signin.html?logout"));
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

This problem occurs when I'm trying to update the SpringSecurity version to latest one and I tried to follow every instruction from official documentation, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to this line in `dbAuthentication(..)` method as you have instantiated the securityContext.

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
```

The problem is, that you are getting the SecurityContext from SecurityContextHolder and trying to set the Authentication value which is not recommended.
You need to populate the security context as

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
Authentication authentication =
    new TestingAuthenticationToken("username", "password", "ROLE_USER");
context.setAuthentication(authentication);

SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
```

Only then, you will be able to use it.

Regarding not being able to find it in the documentation, Here is the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-securitycontextholder) to the official doc on setting SecurityContext.